# "Make" instead of "choose as"

Tags: word-usage

Our school chose an arrogant girl as a "prefect". So a kid said:

> Who **made** you a prefect? You're so snobbish and stuck-up.

Does "make" here sound natural instead of "choose as"?

Comment: They always do that.

Comment: What do they always do @AIQ?

Comment: @It's About Eng - "they" = "schools", and "do that" = "choose arrogant individuals as prefects".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, 'make' here is normal and idiomatic.

> make verb (CAUSE TO BE)   [ T ]
>   to cause to be, to become, or to
>   appear as:
>
> The president has made Henry Paulson his Secretary of the Treasury.

[Make (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/make)